# How to show a layout into another view by programming?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to inflate a layout and show it to a view group. How can I do this?

I have my custom Layout file `target_view_layout.xml` in resource/layout directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/targetCardViewId"
...
```

In the activity.xml file I have a view:

```
...

<View
            android:id="@+id/targetViewId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
...
```

Inside activity java file I tried this:

```java
        private View targetView;
        targetView = findViewById(R.id.targetViewId);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        targetView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.target_view_layout,null);
```

how can I attach the inflated view into `targetView` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Do you mean to inflate `target_view_layout` _into_ `targetViewId`?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying something like that

Comment: Then `targetView` needs to be some sort of `ViewGroup` – e.g., a `<FrameLayout>`, `<LinearLayout>`, etc. – and you can inflate your layout directly into it with something like: `FrameLayout targetView = findViewById(R.id.targetViewId);`, `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.target_view_layout, targetView);`.

Comment: You mean I've to take <LinearLayout> rather than <View> in my activity.xml file?

Comment: It has to be some sort of `ViewGroup`, because regular `View` cannot have children. There are lots of different `ViewGroup`s available, so pick whichever fits your design best. If the only thing `targetView` is ever going to hold is one copy of `target_view_layout`, then a `<FrameLayout>` would be appropriate. If instead you mean to stack several of them vertically, for example, a `<LinearLayout>` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intention is to inflate the target_view_layout.xml into your activity layout view with id targetViewId, if that's the case try,

```
    private View targetView;
            targetView = findViewById(R.id.targetViewId);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.target_view_layout,null);
            targetView.add(child);
```

Comment: Cant't find targetView.add(child), no such method.

Comment: That's maybe your custom view is not a container/parent. Make your custom view extend one of Android container classes like, RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Problem solved by replacing  `<View>` to `<LinearLayout>`  in `activity.xml` file and in java file taking `private LinearLayout targetView`. But how can I extend a View to container class?

Comment: @philoopher97 you can create your own custom view that extends container views. Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198222/6561178

Answer (score 1):

Your current code only just assigns the inflated view to the variable targetView, what you wanna do is add the inflated view inside the targetView
Use View.add(View view) function to achieve that

```
private View targetView;
private View view;
targetView = findViewById(R.id.targetViewId);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.target_view_layout,null);
targetView.add(view)'
```

Comment: can't find targetView.add(). No such method in targetView.

Comment: Just use any of the viewgroups(FrameLayout, LinearLayout, etc) instead of your view in XML

Comment: Problem solved by replacing <View> to <LinearLayout> in activity.xml file and in java file taking private LinearLayout targetView. Thanks for your answer.